# Lack of data using golang channel

Tags: go, channel

I encountered a strange problem. The script is below.

```
package main

import (
    "fmt"
    "sync"
)

type Data struct {
    data []int
}

func main() {
    ws := 5
    ch := make(chan *Data, ws)
    var wg sync.WaitGroup
    for i := 0; i < ws; i++ {
        wg.Add(1)
        go func(wg *sync.WaitGroup, ch chan *Data) {
            defer wg.Done()
            for {
                char, ok := <-ch
                if !ok {
                    return
                }
                fmt.Printf("Get: %d\n", len(char.data))
            }
        }(&wg, ch)
    }
    var d Data
    ar := []int{1}
    for i := 0; i < ws; i++ {
        d.data = []int{}
        for j := 0; j < 1000; j++ {
            d.data = append(d.data, ar[0])
        }
        ch <- &d
        // time.Sleep(time.Second / 1000) // When this line is moved, a number of data by put and get becomes same.
        fmt.Printf("Put: %d\n", len(d.data))
    }
    close(ch)
    wg.Wait()
}
```

This is run, a following result is expected. The number of data for "Put" and "Get" is same.

```
Put: 1000
Get: 1000
Put: 1000
Get: 1000
Put: 1000
Get: 1000
Put: 1000
Get: 1000
Put: 1000
Get: 1000
```

But, this result cannot be got every time. The results are below. The number of data of "Put" and "Get" is different for every time.

**Try 1**

```
Put: 1000
Get: 1000
Put: 1000
Get: 1000
Put: 1000
Get: 1000
Put: 1000
Get: 1000
Put: 1000
Get: 1000
```

**Try 2**

```
Put: 1000
Get: 1000
Put: 1000
Get: 1000
Put: 1000
Get: 1000
Put: 1000
Get: 16
Put: 1000
Get: 0
```

**Try 3**

```
Get: 1000
Put: 1000
Put: 1000
Get: 1
Put: 1000
Get: 1000
Put: 1000
Get: 1
Put: 1000
Get: 1000
```

ALthough on my PC, the number of data of "Put" and "Get" is different for every time, at play.golang.org, the number of both data is always same. https://play.golang.org/p/QFSuZmZk7d Why?

If `time.Sleep(time.Second / 1000)` is used in the script, the number of both data becomes same. If you know about this problem, will you please teach me. Thank you so much for your time.

Comment: You pass a pointer to the same structure into multiple workers, and access to the structure is not syncrhonised. So after you have passed a pointer and between data was extracted from it you may have cleared the `.data` property and started filling it with new data.

Comment: If you move the `var d Data` declaration into the loop body it should work as expected. Alternatively you can use `chan Data` channel type, in that case the `Data` structure would copy every time implicitly.

Comment: @zerkms Thank you so much for your comments and support. I could understand the reason of this problem. I found that there are several methods for solving. I really appreciate. At this time, I would like to solve this by including ``var d Data`` in loop. By the way, this was solved. What should I do for this?

Comment: I have posted slightly extended version as an answer, now you may check it using the green checkmark button on the left. And welcome to the stackoverflow :-)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What you observe is an example of "data race".

It happens when you concurrently access the same piece of data (with at least one of those being a write).

You put a reference to the same structure every time. And what may happen next is one of few possibilities:

1. it was read on the other side of the channel before you mutated it (the "expected" scenario)
2. you started mutating it before it was read. In this case the receiver may read any number of `Data.data` items, from 0 to 1000, depending on when exactly the read happened.

There are multiple solutions for the problem:

1. You may create the new instance of `Data` every iteration. For that simply move the `var d Data` declaration inside the loop body. In this case every iteration a new structure is created, so you may not mutate the previous one by mistake.
2. You may declare channel of `Data` (the structures, not pointers to a structure): `chan Data`. In this case the `Data` instance is implicitly copied every time you send it to the channel (since everything in Go is passed by value, copied on assignment).

Comment: Thank you very much for your advices. I pushed the checkmark now. I wanted to push a vote of useful. But it wasn't reflected. It seems that I cannot use it yet. I'm sorry.

Answer (score 0):

```
package main

import (
    "fmt"
    "sync"
)

/*
    信号量的考察，put 之后，必须等待 get 拿到之后才能推出循环
*/

type Data struct {
    data []int
}

func main() {
    ws := 5
    ch := make(chan *Data, ws)

    sem := make(chan bool)

    var wg sync.WaitGroup

    for i := 0; i < ws; i++ {
        wg.Add(1)

        go func(wg *sync.WaitGroup, ch chan *Data) {
            defer wg.Done()

            for {
                char, ok := <-ch
                if !ok {
                    return
                }
                fmt.Printf("Get: %d\n", len(char.data))
                sem <- true
            }
        }(&wg, ch)
    }

    var d Data
    ar := []int{1}

    // ws = 5
    for i := 0; i < ws; i++ {
        d.data = []int{}

        for j := 0; j < 1000; j++ {
            d.data = append(d.data, ar[0])
        }

        ch <- &d

        fmt.Printf("Put: %d\n", len(d.data))

        <-sem // 一个信号量，必须等待 get 完成之后才能继续put
    }
    close(ch)

    wg.Wait()
}
```

Comment: Thank you for this code snippet, which might provide some limited short-term help.  A proper explanation [would greatly improve](//meta.stackexchange.com/q/114762) its long-term value by showing *why* this is a good solution to the problem, and would make it more useful to future readers with other, similar questions.  Please [edit] your answer to add some explanation, including the assumptions you've made.